# CTE + INSERT INTO + SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, db2, common-table-expression

I am trying to insert some date into another table. At first I´ve tried to use sqlalchemy to create such queries, but as I got some error when executing, I tried to solve it through raw SQL, but the error still the same.

I am not very used to CTE commands, so I don´t know if there are some restrinctions over them.

```
WITH Conv_Pre_Pagos AS 
(SELECT CONVENIO.COD_IDEN, CONVENIO.D_CLIENTE_NOM
FROM db2rpc.CONVENIO 
WHERE CONVENIO.COD_ESPC = 52) 

INSERT INTO DB2I023A.ANL_TARF_PAGAS_PREPAGO (convenio, convenente) SELECT CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM, Conv_Pre_Pagos.D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM DB2TFA.CBR_TARF_REC JOIN Conv_Pre_Pagos ON CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM = Conv_Pre_Pagos.COD_IDEN
```

The sentence is bigger, but I removed some data to bring it cleaner. Still, the same error:

```
ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: SQLNumResultCols failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "INSERT" following "INSERT" is not valid.  
   Expected tokens may include:  "(SELECT ,".  SQLSTATE=42601  SQLCODE=-199 

[SQL: WITH Conv_Pre_Pagos AS (SELECT CONVENIO.COD_IDEN, CONVENIO.D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM db2rpc.CONVENIO WHERE CONVENIO.COD_ESPC = 52) 

INSERT INTO DB2I023A.ANL_TARF_PAGAS_PREPAGO (convenio, convenente) 
SELECT CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM, Conv_Pre_Pagos.D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM DB2TFA.CBR_TARF_REC JOIN Conv_Pre_Pagos ON CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM = Conv_Pre_Pagos.COD_IDEN] 

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)"
```

Where does it see an "insert following insert"?

Comment: I don't see an insert following insert either. Maybe there is more code that is involved here?

Comment: There isn´t. This is the full code

sql = '''WITH Conv_Pre_Pagos AS 
(SELECT CONVENIO.COD_IDEN, CONVENIO.D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM db2rpc.CONVENIO
WHERE CONVENIO.COD_ESPC = 52)

INSERT INTO DB2I023A.ANL_TARF_PAGAS_PREPAGO (convenio, convenente) 
SELECT CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM, Conv_Pre_Pagos.D_CLIENTE_NOM
FROM DB2TFA.CBR_TARF_REC JOIN Conv_Pre_Pagos ON CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM = Conv_Pre_Pagos.COD_IDEN'''

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(text(sql))

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=statement-common-table-expression

If I got it right, "use of common table expressions is not allowed in a INSERT within SELECT statement.". I Think that it´s my case.  I don´t know if it is a IBM DB2 Z/OS restriction or a CTE common restriction.

Comment: There's no particular reason here for a CTE that I can see. Just do a regular join maybe?

Comment: I could use it by moving to a sub query instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO DB2I023A.ANL_TARF_PAGAS_PREPAGO (convenio, convenente)

WITH Conv_Pre_Pagos AS 
(
SELECT CONVENIO.COD_IDEN, CONVENIO.D_CLIENTE_NOM
FROM db2rpc.CONVENIO 
WHERE CONVENIO.COD_ESPC = 52
) 
SELECT CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM, Conv_Pre_Pagos.D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM DB2TFA.CBR_TARF_REC 
JOIN Conv_Pre_Pagos ON CBR_TARF_REC.NR_DOC_SIS_OGM = Conv_Pre_Pagos.COD_IDEN
```

Comment: Interesting that using the syntaxe as you suggested does not work (""CONVENIO.COD_IDEN" is not valid in the context where it is used"), but if I remove the table name in front of the column name all over the query, it works.

Comment: INSERT INTO DB2I023A.ANL_TARF_PAGAS_PREPAGO (convenio, convenente)

WITH Conv_Pre_Pagos AS 
(
SELECT COD_IDEN, D_CLIENTE_NOM
FROM db2rpc.CONVENIO 
WHERE COD_ESPC = 52
) 
SELECT NR_DOC_SIS_OGM, D_CLIENTE_NOM 
FROM DB2TFA.CBR_TARF_REC  
JOIN Conv_Pre_Pagos ON NR_DOC_SIS_OGM = COD_IDEN